# How do I access child elements within riot.js

Tags: javascript, web-component, riot.js

If I have a custom `riot` tag with a `p` in it like this:

```
<custom>
  <p>This is a text</p>
</custom>
```

How do I access the `<p>` element from within the `<custom>` tag?

***Update**:* I've received a whole bunch answers that are of ways to select it from the DOM. What I want is a way to select the inner `p` tag from within the component library [riot.js](https://github.com/muut/riotjs) itself. I'm looking for a more riotjs specific answer. For example with [polymer](https://github.com/polymer/polymer) you use `this.$.content.getDistributedNodes()`.

Comment: `this.root.children[0].innerText` looks like it gets me the text.

Comment: BTW, there is a pure js version: `document.querySelector('custom').children[0].innerHTML`. See [`document#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelector?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelector).

Comment: [riot.js](https://muut.com/riotjs/api/) is a minimal library focused at accomplishing a single specific task. It's supposed to be used together with other tools, not to be a "blanket" framework. Its documentation suggests there are no such methods and the answers below (using native DOM API) are correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Riot only provides 4 properties to access data from the current tag you're in:

- this.opts
- this.parent
- this.root
- this.tags

[See the API docs](https://muut.com/riotjs/api/#tag-instance)

**edit**

Besides this you can directly access `named elements`:

```
<my-tag>
  <p name="foo">Hi, I'm foo</p>
  <script>
    console.log(this.foo);
  </script>
</my-tag>
```

[see the docs](https://muut.com/riotjs/guide/#named-elements)

**/edit**

<s>There's no direct reference to any of the elements you defined in your custom-tag;</s> the rest comes down to just pure old JS (which you might favour or not).

Like others stated, you can access elements using dom methods. However, in some cases you need to wait until the DOM is actually loaded. For instance:

```
<my-tag>
  <p>yada</p>
  <script>
    console.log(this.root.querySelector('p'))
  </script>
</my-tag>
```

won't work, because the DOM is not ready yet. Instead wrap the selector in a 'mount' event listener like this:

```
<my-tag>
  <p>yada</p>
  <script>
    this.on('mount', function() {
      console.log(this.root.querySelector('p'))
    })
  </script>
</my-tag>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you add an id or name attribute to your inner tag, you can access it via `self`.

```
// with 'id'
<custom><p id="pTest">Test</p></custom>

// with 'name'
<custom><p name="pTest">Test</p></custom>
```

in js part:

```
self = this

self.pTest
>>  <p id=pTest>Test</p>
```

Tested in Riot v2.0.10

Answer (score 5):

See [Tag instance](https://muut.com/riotjs/api/#tag-instance).

We can access to `children`.

```
customTagAndLoops = this.children
```

Also to DOM via `root`.

```
iAmDom = this.root
childNodes = this.root.childNodes
p = this.root.querySelector('p')
```

**UPDATE - Feb 14, 2015**

`children` property is obsoleted in Riot.js v2.0.9. The only way to access child elements is using `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Riotjs in latest versions has `Yielding nested HTML` feature.
[See the API docs](http://riotjs.com/api/#a-nameyielda-yielding-nested-html)

In your case you can easily do that in this way:

**In tag definition:**

```
<custom>
 <!-- tag markup-->
 <div id="place for custom html">
   <yield/>
 </div>
</custom>
```

**In your app:**

```
<custom>
  <p>This is a text</p>
</custom>
```

**Rendered html:**

```
<custom>
  <div id="place for custom html">
    <p>This is a text</p>
  </div>
</custom>
```

From the docs

> The `<yield>` tag also provides a slot mechanism that allows you to inject html contents on specific slots in the template

Answer (score 1):

In riot 3.4.2 you can add a ref attribute to the inner element that you want ej:

```
<custom>
  <p ref="myP">This is a text</p>
</custom>
...

// in js
this.refs.myP
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('custom');
for (var i = 0; i< nodes.length; ++i) {
    paragraphs = nodes[i].getElementsByTagName('p');
    alert(paragraphs[0].innerText);
}
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns an HTML Collection which you can further query: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Here's a quick and dirty fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markm/m8n3huLn/

Answer (score 0):

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) seems to work with custom tags:

```js
document.querySelector('custom p').innerHTML= 'Test complete';
```

```html
<p>This is a test</p>
<custom>
  <p>This is a test</p>
</custom>
<p>This is a test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The RiotJs [Cheatsheet](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/riot.html#nested-html) suggests using yield, if I have understood your dilemma correctly.

Main tag declaration:

```html
<element-i-will-call>

  <span>I am a title</span>

  <element-child-as-container>
    <yield to='header'>Hello User</yield>
    <yield to='conent'>You are here</yield>
  </element-child-as-container>

</element-i-will-call>
```

Child tag declaration:

```html
<element-child-as-container>

  <h2>
    <yield from='header'/>
  </h2>

  <div>
    <yield from='conent'/>
  </div>

</element-child-as-container>
```

Main implementation:

```html
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <element-i-will-call />
</body>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

https://riot.js.org/api/#-yielding-nested-html

if you have this in your html:

```
<custom>
  <p>This is a text</p>
</custom>
```

Then in your tag file you can use `<yield/>`

```
<custom>
    <yield/>
</custom>
```

This will now make the `<p>` render on the page