# Riot.js: How to catch an event in sub tag with Observable pattern?

Tags: riot.js

I want to be able to create an reuseable subtag:

```
<tag>
  <subtag id=subtag></subtag>
</tag>
```

Therefor I would like to use the observable pattern to communicate with the sub tag:

```
var self = this

subtag = riot.mount('#subtag')[0]

subtag.on('clicked', function(){
  console.log('subtag has been clicked)
})
```

The code does not work since  was already mounted.
If I place the subtag outside the tag, it does however work.
How to catch an event using the sub tag notation?

Answer (score 0):

Since riot.js v2.0.13 all named subtags are accessible using `self.<id>`, see for details:
[How do I access child elements within riot.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28246140/how-do-i-access-child-elements-within-riot-js/28605875#28605875)